# How to know (in a backing bean) which p:commandButton was clicked?

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton

I want to know if the user clicked on a specific [commandButton](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml) and, if so, then perform some stuff:

The xhtml:

```
<h:form id="myFormID">
    <p:commandButton id="myButtonID" actionListener="#{myController.save}" ... >
...
```

The backing bean method:

```
public void someMethod(ActionEvent event) {
    CommandButton commandButton = (CommandButton) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("myFormID:myButtonID");
    if (commandButton.whichMethodHere()) {
        //do some stuff
    }
...
```

Does anyone knows which method I can use to know if the commandButton was clicked?

Comment: look at the API for the Action event... it is already there, but wouldn't it be better to have two explicit methods?

Comment: I've already searched in the [API](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/component/commandbutton/CommandButton.html), there is a lot of methods and, as I tested those which I thought that was the correct, but didn't worked as I expected, that's exactly why I've posted this question here.

Comment: Then you made an error... If you have the component, you get its id if relevant.

Comment: And read my comment carefully, look for the actionEvent API... It has the component that initiated the request

Comment: Kukeltje, if I have more time here in my job, believe me, I would read and learn much more. Thanks again for the hint, you saved me much time !

Comment: In case someone wants to know, I resolved this ways: `CommandButton commandButton = (CommandButton) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("DemandasListForm:trashButton");
UIComponent component = event.getComponent();

if (commandButton.getId().equals(component.getId())) {
    //do some stuff
... `

Comment: Why, this complex? Wht not compare `component.getId().equals("DemandasListForm:trashButton")`

Comment: Ok, even better this way! Thanks! But the comparision is not correct, since [getId()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getId--) returns the string name of the component. So, I did: `if (component.getId().equals("trashButton"))` to get it right.

Comment: try the getClientId() saver in some ways but a little risk when movimg the compoment ro another parent. Better to use two methods